# Pointer conversion issue with Ternary operator

Tags: c++, conditional-operator, null-pointer, c++builder-2010, constant-expression

I know the ternary operator has some surprising restrictions, but I was a bit baffled that this fails to compile for me:

```
void foo(bool b)
{
    int* ptr =  ((b) ? NULL : NULL);
}
```

Obviously that's the minimum needed to show the problem. The error is:

```
[BCC32 Error] Unit11.cpp(20): E2034 Cannot convert 'int' to 'int *'
```

Compiler is the less-than-100%-conforming Embarcadero C++Builder 2010, so a compiler bug is far from impossible...

NOTE: Parens modified to avoid confusion about my intent.

NOTE2: I'd got myself a little confused about how I'd arrived at this construct in the first place, so here's my excuse: I was getting some compilation errors on a line like `a = b? c : d`, where b, c and d were all complex expressions. To narrow it down, I replaced `c` and `d` with `NULL`s in order to check if `b` was the culprit. At this point, everything went to hell in a handcart.

Comment: GCC is fine with it: http://www.ideone.com/ddUyR. :(

Comment: +1 for a minimally complete example program.

Comment: If you're compiler supported C++0x you could use `nullptr` however `NULL` is really a macro defined as a literal integer in most implementations. i.e `#define NULL 0`

Comment: Embarcadero appreciate bug reports.  You can log it here: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx

Comment: @David M: Thanks, I wanted to get consensus here before QC'ing it. And consenus is it's not a bug!

Comment: @AJG85 : Encouragingly, the IDE highlights `nullptr` as a keyword, but sadly the compiler barfs. BCB2010 has some C++0x goodness, but not all.

Comment: @Roddy I don't think any compiler supports it all yet as it isn't finalized ... I sorely wish VS2010 had variadic templates.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`NULL` is a macro that expands to `0` (or some integral constant expression with a value of `0`, for example, `(1 - 1)`).  It's not otherwise "special."

Any integral constant expression with a value of zero is usable as a null pointer constant, which is the reason that `int* ptr = 0;` is permitted.  However, here, the expression is `b ? 0 : 0`; this is not an integral constant expression (`b` is not constant); its type is `int`, which is not implicitly convertible to `int*`

The workaround would be to explicitly specify that you want a pointer type:

```
int* const null_int_ptr = 0;
int* ptr = b ? null_int_ptr : null_int_ptr;
```

The example is a bit contrived, though:  usually when one uses the conditional operator, at least one of the arguments is actually a pointer type (e.g. `b ? ptr : 0`); when one of the operands is a pointer type, the `0` is implicitly converted to that same pointer type and thus the type of the entire conditional expression is the pointer type, not `int`.

The only case where you can have this "problem" is where a null pointer constant is used as both the second and third operands of the conditional operator, which is rather odd.

Comment: What about `nullptr` from C++11? Would `int* ptr = b ? nullptr : nullptr;` work?

Comment: @Martinho:  Perhaps; I have not yet had the opportunity to use `nullptr`.

Comment: Actually, that compiles in gcc for some reason. Checked after I wrote my answer :)

Comment: Yes, `nullptr` would compile just fine, as the result type will be `nullptr_t`. This kind of thing is why `nullptr` was added to the language.

Comment: @James - Not sure how contrived. I found this problem with a an `a= b?NULL:c` expression, and then just tried the NULL:NULL to try and reduce the problem further. ... Hmm. I need to re-try some tests here :-(

Comment: @Roddy:  Well, `c` in that case is either (a) a null pointer constant or (b) an actual pointer.  If it's (a) then it doesn't make much sense because the statement is effectively `int* ptr = 0;`; if it's (b), then you should not get this error.

Comment: I think it surprises people that the conditional operator result can be a different type than its parameters; one of my coworkers was convinced there was a C++ bug because of this.

Comment: @James, I worked out how I'd got to the `NULL:NULL` construct - see above. `NULL:x` works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that on your system `NULL` is defined to be `0` which is assumed to be an int in the context of the ternary operator. If you `static_cast` one of the operands to `int*` it should auto-promote the other one.

But why are using such a construct in the first place?

Comment: I was using something like `a = b ? NULL : c;` The `NULL:NULL` just removed an extra piece of context and seemed even more surprising to me.

Comment: Hmmm. maybe I need to go back a step or two in my tests. Watch this space... And thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` could be defined as having type `int` or even `long`, so the ternary operator has the same type. There's no implicit conversion to the pointer type, so compiler generates an error.
The gotcha here is that there is an implicit conversion from constant integer expression evaluating to zero (the infamous null pointer constant).

Possible solution here is an explicit cast:

```
int* ptr =  b ? (int*) NULL : NULL;
```